# How can I compare many datasets update several columns based on the max value of a single column in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have test scores from many students in 8 different years. I want to retain only the max total score of each student, but then also retain all the student-year related information to that test score (that is, all the columns from the same year in which the student got the highest total score).

An example of the datasets I have:

```
%macro score;
%do year = 2010 %to 2018;    
data student_&year.;
do id=1 to 10;
    english=25*rand('uniform');
    math=25*rand('uniform');
    sciences=25*rand('uniform');
    history=25*rand('uniform');
    total_score=sum(english, math, sciences, history);
    output;
end;
%end;
run;
%mend;
%score;
```

In my expected output, I would like to retain the max of total_score for each student, and also have the other columns related to that total score. If possible, I would also like to have the information about the year in which the student got the max of total_score. An example of the expected output would be:

```
DATA want;
 INPUT id total_score english math sciences history year;
CARDS;
1 75.4 15.4 20 20 20 2017
2 63.8 20 13.8 10 20 2016
3 48 10 10 18 10 2018
4 52 12 10 10 20 2016
5 69.5 20 19.5 20 10 2013
6 85 20.5 20.5 21 23 2011 
7 41 5 12 14 10 2010
8 55.3 15 20.3 10 10 2012
9 51.5 10 20 10 11.5 2013
10 48.9 12.9 16 10 10 2015
;
RUN;
```

I have been trying to work with the SAS `UPDATE` procedure. But it just get the most recent value for each student. I want the max total score. Also, within the update framework, I need to update two tables at a time. I would like to compare all tables at the same time. So this strategy I am trying does not work:

```
data want;
update score_2010 score_2011;
by id;
```

Thanks to anyone who can provide insights.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that stacks the individual data sets and perform your processing on that.

**Example (SQL `select`, `group by`, and `having`)**

```
data scores / view=scores;
  length year $4;
  set work.student_2010-work.student_2018 indsname=dsname;
  year = scan(dsname,-1,'_');
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from scores
  group by id
  having total_score=max(total_score)
  ;
```

**Example DOW loop processing**

Stack data so the view is processible `BY ID`.  The first DOW loops computes which record has the max total score over the group and the second selects the record in the group for OUTPUT

```
data scores_by_id / view=scores_by_id;
  set work.student_2010-work.student_2018 indsname=dsname;
  by id;
  year = scan(dsname,-1,'_');
run;

data want;
  * compute which record in group has max measure;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);

    set scores_by_id;
    by id;

    if total_score > _max then do; 
      _max = total_score;
      _max_at_n = _n_;
    end;
  end;

  * output entire record having the max measure;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set scores_by_id;
    if _n_ = _max_at_n then OUTPUT;
  end;
  drop _max:;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to obtain what you want if you have only one longitudinal dataset with all the original information of your students. It also makes more sense, since you are comparing students across different years.

To build a longitudinal dataset, you will first need to insert a variable informing the year of each of your original datasets. For example with:

```
%macro score;
%do year = 2010 %to 2018;    
data student_&year.;
do id=1 to 10;
    english=25*rand('uniform');
    math=25*rand('uniform');
    sciences=25*rand('uniform');
    history=25*rand('uniform');
    total_score=sum(english, math, sciences, history);
    year=&year.;
    output;
end;
%end;
run;
%mend;
%score;
```

After including the year, you can get a longitudinal dataset with:

```
data student_allyears;
set student_201:;
run;
```

Finally, you can get what you want with a proc sql, in which you select the max of "total_score" grouped by "id":

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select distinct *
from student_allyears 
group by id
having total_score=max(total_score);
```

Comment: Ok, Richard came first and did better (shorter) than I did. It is basically the same. But perhaps my answer still be useful.